# Is MySecureShell a good way to manage SFTP user with chroot on a Centos Server?

Tags: centos, sftp, ssh, chroot

I need to setup my Centos 5.4 server for SFTP with chrooted access only (or equivalent).
The regular solution using RSSH find here : http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-rssh-chroot-jail-setup.html seems over-killing to me if we want to manage multiple users...

I found the project **MySecureShell** which seems a lot simpler to install and to maintain.

Is it a good solution? Is there something better?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I looked at [scponly](http://sublimation.org/scponly/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/) and various other solutions involving complex configuration and chroot jails, but I found [MySecureShell](http://mysecureshell.free.fr/) to be easy to configure and able to provide exactly what I needed.

It's the only shell I found that could let me [hide files](http://mysecureshell.sourceforge.net/en/HideFiles.html) based on Regular Expressions. That way I can show different users different views of the same file tree.
Along with a properly configured [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) client, it give remote users access to their files in a well integrated and familiar environment, almost just as if they were connecting to a local file server.

Now, there are no installation packages for RedHat/CentOS, which is a shame, but installing from source is trivial. You lose the benefit of automated updates though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best one ;-)

Comment: Why is it the best one?

Comment: Because it doesn't touch any SSH binary, it's simply a shell. Because it is the only one to get so many ACL, because the configuration is very simple and scalable.

Comment: as leader of the MySecureShell I suppose you would say that...
:-)